# Bytes to string to bytes. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

This is a simple question but I cannot seem to figure it out. I want to take the bytes outputted from a `pickle.dumps()` and convert it `str` and be able to convert it back to `bytes` compatible such that `pickle.loads(string_thing)` can recover the original object.

```py
encoded = pickle.dumps(None)
string_encoded = to_string(encoded)
decoded = pickle.loads(safe_decoder(string_encoded))
```

I know one of the objections are going to be, "why do you need to do this?" Restrictions on allowed types.

Comment: What, *specifically*, is wrong with the posted code?

Comment: Base64 encode/decode it…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@deceze gives a good idea: use the module [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) with its functions `.b64encode()` and `.b64decode()`.

Here is an example:

```
>>> 'Álñó@'
'Álñó@'
>>> 'Álñó@'.encode()
b'\xc3\x81l\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb3@'
>>> base64.b64encode('Álñó@'.encode())
b'w4Fsw7HDs0A='
>>> base64.b64encode('Álñó@'.encode()).decode()
'w4Fsw7HDs0A='
```

Now you have a string in base64. For the reverse process:

```
>>> base64.b64encode('Álñó@'.encode()).decode().encode()
b'w4Fsw7HDs0A='
>>> base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode('Álñó@'.encode()).decode().encode())
b'\xc3\x81l\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb3@'
>>> base64.b64decode(base64.b64encode('Álñó@'.encode()).decode().encode()).decode()
'Álñó@'
```

Would that work for you?

---

Example using `pickle`:

```
>>> original_obj = 456.5
>>> original_obj
456.5
>>> type(original_obj)
<class 'float'>
>>> intermediate_str = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(original_obj)).decode()
>>> intermediate_str
'gANHQHyIAAAAAAAu'

>>> new_obj = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(intermediate_str.encode()))
>>> new_obj
456.5
>>> type(new_obj)
<class 'float'>

>>> original_obj == new_obj
True
```

Comment: @deceze I completely forgot about the `base64` module! Thank you very much!